# Calculadora Arduino C++

Tags: c++, arduino

Hola me he hecho una calculadora con un lcd y un tecladito y lo tengo casi listo pero al sumar cualquier numero me da 0, me podrian decir en qué me he eqivocado? gracias. La parte de la sua esta completa pero no me lo suma.

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
//define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypads
String a = "";
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{'1','2','3','+'},
{'4','5','6','-'},
{'7','8','9','*'},
{'-','0','=','/'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {46, 47, 48, 49}; //connect to the row pinouts of 
the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {50, 51, 52, 53}; //connect to the column pinouts 
of the keypad

//initialize an instance of class NewKeypad
Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, 
ROWS, COLS); 


void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
   lcd.begin(199, 1);
   // Print a message to the LCD.

}
int suma = 0;
int resta = 0;
int multi = 0;
int divi = 0;
bool si = true;

char signo = "";
int primer_numero = 0;
int segundo_numero = 0;


void loop() {
  char c = customKeypad.getKey();




if (c){


  if (c == hexaKeys[0][3]) {  //SUMA
     suma = 1; 
     signo = char("+";
  }
 if (c == hexaKeys[1][3]) {  //RESTA
     resta = 1;
     signo = char("-") ;
  }if (c == hexaKeys[2][3]) {  //MULTIPLI
     multi = 1; 
     signo = char("*");
  }if (c == hexaKeys[3][3]) {  //DIVISIO
     divi = 1; 
     signo = char("/");
  }







  if (c == hexaKeys[3][2] && suma == int(1))  {
    si = false;
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print(primer_numero + segundo_numero);
  }
  if(c == hexaKeys[3][2] && resta == int(1)){
    si = false;
    lcd.print(primer_numero - segundo_numero);

  } if (c == hexaKeys[3][2] && multi == int(1)) {
     lcd.print(primer_numero * segundo_numero);
     si = false;
    }

    if (c == hexaKeys[3][2] && divi == int(1)) {
      lcd.print(primer_numero / segundo_numero);
      si = false;
    }


if(si == true){


     a += String(c);
    lcd.print(a);
    Serial.println(c);
    // set the cursor to column 0, line 1 


   lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  }
   if (c != hexaKeys[0][3] && hexaKeys[1][3] && hexaKeys[2][3] && 
   hexaKeys[3][3] ){
   String(primer_numero) +=  String(c);
  if(primer_numero > 0){
    String(segundo_numero) += String(c);
     }
   } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Puede ser que el error este en el ultimo if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (c == hexaKeys[3][2] && suma == int(1)) {
```

Hasta donde llego después de leer tu código, `hexaKeys[3][2]` se corresponde con la tecla `*`, cuando en `c` encontrarás  `+`... ¿no te fias del estado de las variables de tu propio programa?

Con esto debería valer:

```
void loop () {
  suma = 0;

  if (suma == 1) {
```

Pero claro... puede ser un autentico caos tener que gestionar 4 variables que son excluyentes entre sí... es decir, solo puede estar una activa... para este tipo de situaciones se inventaron los enumerados:

```
enum Operacion
{
  NINGUNA,
  SUMA,
  RESTA,
  PRODUCTO,
  DIVISION,
};
```

Con lo que tu codigo ahora quedaría asi:

```
void loop()
{
  char c = customKeypad.getKey();
  Operacion op = NINGUNA;

  if (c == 0 )
    return;

  if (c == hexaKeys[0][3])
    op = SUMA;
  else if (c == hexaKeys[1][3])
    op = RESTA;
  else if (c == hexaKeys[2][3])
    op = PRODUCTO;
  else if (c == hexaKeys[3][3])
    op = DIVISION;

  switch( op )
  {
    case SUMA:
      // si = false; <<--- no es necesario
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(primer_numero + segundo_numero);
      break;

    case RESTA:

    // ...

    default:
      // aqui el codigo de si == true
  }
}
```

Aunque fíjate que podrias ponerlo dentro todo dentro de la cadena de `if` que determinan la operación... no lo he hecho para que ambos códigos se parezcan un poco.